# How can I get extra attention for my question when I don't have enough rep for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have recently joined Stack Overflow and I've asked a question but I got no reply. What can I do if I do not have enough reputation to put a bounty on it? How can I get some extra attention for my question?

Comment: comment on your other question (because you deleted it): you realize that if you are a mod that you still can't magically make your posts un-downvotable? Also, you have to be elected by the community, and if you keep asking bad questions, you definitely won't be. So, this is how to make your posts not get downvotes: stop posting bad questions!

Comment: Post a link on Twitter.

Answer (score 8):

1. You asked it 4 hours ago. Have some patience.
2. [The question is off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708208/how-to-install-rpm-files-in-fedora-17) (now deleted - +10k users link) - why do you expect an answer when the question doesn't even belong on the site?